# What semantic notions underlie the prefixes 'con-' and 'de-' (+ notare) with the logical concepts of 'con/de-notation'?

Tags: philosophy-terms

<sub>Source: Hurley, Patrick J. *A Concise Introduction to Logic* (2014 12 ed, but ∃ [2017 13 ed](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1305958098)). p. 92 Middle.</sub>

> The previous section of this chapter explored the cognitive meaning of language in
>   general. The cognitive meaning of terms comprises two kinds: intensional and extensional. The **intensional meaning**, or **intension**, consists of the qualities or attributes
>   that the term *connotes*, and the **extensional meaning**, or **extension**, consists of the
>   members of the class that the term *denotes*. For example, the intensional meaning of
>   the term “cat” consists of the attributes of being furry, of having four legs, of moving
>   in a certain way, of emitting certain sounds, and so on, while the extensional meaning
>   consists of cats themselves—all the cats in the universe. The term connotes the attributes and denotes the cats.
>     The intensional meaning of a term is otherwise known as the **connotation**, and the
>   extensional meaning is known as the **denotation**. *Intension* and *extension* are roughly
>   equivalent to the more modern terms *sense* and *reference*, respectively. Also, note that
>   logic uses the terms *connotation* and *denotation* differently from the way they are used
>   in grammar. In grammar, *connotation* refers to the subtle nuances of a word, whereas
>   *denotation* refers to the word’s direct and specific meaning.

I do not understand the word choices of **con/de-notation**. Because **con/de-notation** share the same root and differ only in prefix, I conjecture this difference in prefixes to distinguish the logical concepts above. To save space, I link to the references; but tell me if I should reproduce them.

Etymonline for [connote](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=connote&allowed_in_frame=0), [connotation](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=connotation&allowed_in_frame=0), [denote](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=denote&allowed_in_frame=0), [denotation](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=denotation).

OED for [connote](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/39390?redirectedFrom=connote#eid), [connotation](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/39386?redirectedFrom=connotation#eid), [denote](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/50010?redirectedFrom=denote#eid), [denotation](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/50007?redirectedFrom=denotation#eid).

Wiktionary for [connote](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/connote), [connotation](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/connotation), [denote](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/denote), [denotation](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/denotation).

Comment: Can you explain exactly what you find confusing?

Answer (score 3):

I think there is a simple explanation for these two meanings: [*noto, -are*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dnoto), the base word, means "to signify, indicate, denote."

- **Denoto**

  The prefix [*de-*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dde2) can mean many things, such as "down" or "ending." In this case, however, it simply strenghtens the idea, as noted in L&S II.2.c.:

  > With reference to the terminus of the action; with reference to the extent of the action, to the uttermost, to exhaustion, through. out; **hence freq. a mere strengthening of the fundamental idea, = valde, thoroughly, much**

  *Denoto* thus refers to the action of "signifying something." It really is not much different from *noto*.
- **Connoto**

  The prefix [*com-/con-*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dcum1) most frequently signifies:

  > A being or bringing together of several objects

  *Connoto* (which does not have classical examples) refers to the act of "signifying *along with* something else." A **connotation** refers to all the ideas/things/emotions that "go along with" something. Although the object does not *mean* these things, its meaning "carries along with it" that extra baggage.

As a general comment about this kind of question: tracking down the reason behind certain meanings is not really a deductive exercise. Nuances of meaning are crystallized by usage--guided, of course, by meaning but not determined by them.